# Tkinter Options menu not displaying Selected value in option menu in Python

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter.optionmenu

Tkinter Options Menu not displaying selection receiving below error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set'
```

Used this code to add dynamic list to the option menu. Option menu changing dynamically when new list is generated but when select the item  from the list the above error is coming

```
dropdownmenu=StringVar()
om=dropdownmenu.set("Select any section")
lst=final_key_list
drop_menu=drop.children['menu']
for val in lst:
   drop_menu.add_command(label=val,command=lambda v=om,l=val:v.set(1))
```

Comment: `dropdownmenu.set()` doesn't return anything, so why did you assign it to `om`?  Also I believe you have a confusion between `l` and `1` in your lambda.

Comment: I want to show first option as "Select any section" when clicking the drop down list will be visible. If i want to use lambda command means whether i have to use 1=val or L=val?. If i am wrong please correct me.

Comment: I do not understand the code after the lambda command i just replicate it based  on my code answers were found 

v=om,l=val:v.set(1))

Comment: @jasonharper I got your point. I have corrected om and 1 in the code it fixed the issue.